# Getting troubles when trying to install FOSUserBundle to Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I'm trying to install FOSUserBundle I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::getManager() in W:\symproject\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1039
```

What can it be?

I've also tried to install FOSUserBundle to a pure Symfony Standart Edition and encountered the same issue.

I followed along [this documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have installed latest FOSUserBundle which is used for Symfony2.1.x
If you are using Symfony2.0.x change your deps file:

```
[FOSUserBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/UserBundle
    version=1.2.0
```

then reinstall the vendors with:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

Comment: version should be origin/1.2.x

Answer (score 1):

I have been using FOS User Bundle for a long time, and this weekend my automatic build stopped working with exactly the error you wrote here. So for me I then found the solution :)

It seems like the latest version of FOS User Bundle has a bug, so I added this to the `deps.lock` file:

```
FOSUserBundle f487dc16cec6003c46542a90d5193761fd91360a
```

In deps file I have:

```
[FOSUserBundle]
git=http://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git
target=bundles/FOS/UserBundle
```

And voila! It now works!

(The commit f487d... was just chosen from the commits 4 days ago - when I know it was working)

This should fix your problem!

Comment: It helped! I downloaded it from here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I've updated from 2.0.16 to 2.1 dev-master with composer, got the same error...
my solution:

In `orm.xml`

```
factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getManager"
```

**replace with**

```
factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getEntityManager"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are using Symfony 2.0.x there's not such method as *getManager*, instead you have to use *getEntityManager* to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have missed Doctrine ORM mapping in config.yml

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    FOSUserBundle: ~

try this hope this will work...